# Pass values in an array to redshift parameterized query using map function

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to insert an array of objects in the redshift database using the parameterized query. I have used map function and called an event to iterate through the objects in the array.

```
try {
        responseBody = redshiftClient.parameterizedQuery( 'INSERT INTO tablename (id, test1, test2, test3, test4, test5) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)',  
        [event.map(item => [id, item.test1, item.test2, item.test3,item.test4, test5])]);
    } catch ( err ) {
      console.log(err);
    } 
    var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {

        },
        "body": JSON.stringify(responseBody),
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    console.log('Response'+response);
    return response;
```

The map function does not iterate through each objects in the array and returns the following error.

```
 "error Message": "error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement \"\" requires 6",
```

Is there any other available methods to insert values in the array?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple values can be passed for parameterized query insertion using the npm package `pg-format`. This format helps in passing the parameters as an array. pg-format provides the %L pattern that outputs an escaped SQL literal.

Kindly refer to the link https://www.wlaurance.com/2018/09/node-postgres-insert-multiple-rows